# What trace-token option for gcloud is used for?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Help definition is not clear for me:

> Token used to route traces of service requests for investigation of
> issues.

Could you provide simple example how to use it?
I tried:

```
gcloud compute instances create vm3 --trace-token xyz123
```

I can find "vm3" string in logs, but not my token xyz123.
The only use of it seems to be in grep:

```
history| grep xyz123
```

Comment: My answer was incorrect and so I've deleted it; I've now tried what I suggested. Actually, when you include the `--trace-token` flag with `gcloud`, the CLI appends (!) a property `trace` with a URL-encoded value of `token:${TOKEN}` to the REST calls' querystrings. The trace token is not represented by a header as I'd thought. The trace token may be provided|used by Cloud Support to help debug REST API calls.

Answer (score 0):

The flag --trace-token is intended to be used by the support agents when there is some error which is difficult to track from the logs. The Google Cloud Platform Support agent provides a time bound token which will expire after a specified time and asks the user to run the command for the specific product in which the user is facing the issue. Then it gets easier for the support agent to trace the error by using that --trace-token.

For example :

A user faced some error while creating a Compute Engine instance and contacted the Google Cloud Platform Support team. The support agent then inspected the logs and other resources but could not find the root cause of the issue. Then the support agent provides a --trace-token and asks the user to run the below command with the provided --trace-token.

```
--trace-token = abcdefgh
```

Command : `gcloud compute instances create my-vm --trace-token abcdefgh`

After the user runs the above command the support agent could find the error by analysing in depth with the help of the --trace-token

Please note that when a --trace-token flag is used the content of the trace may include sensitive information like auth tokens, the contents of any accessed files. Hence they should only be used for manual testing and should not be used in production environments.